# Time object to String Object to XML and Back Again in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, time

I am storing Time objects in XML as strings. I am having trouble figuring out the best way to reinitialize them back. From strings to Time objects in order to perform a subtraction on them.

here is how they are stored in xml

```
        <time>
        <category> batin </category>
        <in>2014-10-29 18:20:47 -0400</in>
        <out>2014-10-29 18:20:55 -0400</out>
    </time>
```

using

```
 t = Time.now
```

i am accessing them from xml with

```
        doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("time.xml"))
        nodes = doc.xpath("//time").each do |node|
        temp = TimeClock.new
        temp.category = node.xpath('category').inner_text
        temp.in = node.xpath('in').inner_text.
        temp.out = node.xpath('out').inner_text.
        @times << temp
    end
```

what is the best way to reconvert them back to Time objects? i do not see a method of Time object that does this. I found that it is possible to convert to a Date object. but that seems to only give me a format of mm/dd/yyyy which is partly what i want.

in need to be able to subtract

```
<out>2014-10-29 18:20:55 -0400</out>
```

from

```
<in>2014-10-29 18:20:47 -0400</in>
```

the XML will at some point be stored based on dates but i also need the exact time "hh/mm/ss" as well to perform calculations.

any sugguestions?

Comment: Your sample input XML isn't valid according to your code.

Comment: i left out the parts that do not pertain to the question im asking.

Comment: You left out parts that pertain to the code. We need to see a working sample. As is we have to cobble up sample input to show you how to do this correctly.

Comment: See "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html) stdlib extends the class with parsing/conversion methods.

```
require 'time'
Time.parse('2014-10-29 18:20:47 -0400')
```

Comment: temp.in = Time.parse(node.xpath('in').inner_text) worked very well ty!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'time'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<xml>
<time>
<category>
  <in>2014-10-29 18:20:47 -0400</in>
  <out>2014-10-29 18:20:55 -0400</out>
</category>
</time>
</xml>
EOT

times = doc.search('time category').map{ |category|
  in_time, out_time = %w[in out].map{ |n| Time.parse(category.at(n).text) }
  {
    in: in_time,
    out: out_time
  }
}

times # => [{:in=>2014-10-29 15:20:47 -0700, :out=>2014-10-29 15:20:55 -0700}]
```

Both the [DateTime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse) and [Time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-parse) classes allow parsing of a small variety of date/time formats. Some formats can cause explosions but this one is safe. Use DateTime if the date could be before the Unix epoch.

---

```
in_time, out_time = %w[in out].map{ |n| Time.parse(category.at(n).text) }
```

Looking at that in IRB:

```
>> doc.search('time category').to_html
"<category>\n  <in>2014-10-29 18:20:47 -0400</in>\n  <out>2014-10-29 18:20:55 -0400</out>\n</category>"
```

`doc.search('time category')` returns a NodeSet of all `<category>` nodes.

```
>> %w[in out]
[
    [0] "in",
    [1] "out"
]
```

returns an array of strings.

```
Time.parse(category.at(n).text)
```

returns the `n` node under the `<category>` node, where `n` is first `'in'`, then `'out'`.